# Finding combinations of values across multiple rows and columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I am trying to create all possible sets of values from a pandas dataframe, taking 3 values from each row.

For example, if I consider the dataframe below:

```
0           1             2            3             4              5               6
Table       Black         Brown       Red           Blue          Green          Amber
Chair       Magenta       Turquoise   White         Orange        Violet         Pink
Window      Indigo        Yellow      Cerulean      Grey          Peach          Aqua
```

I want to generate all possible solution sets, by taking 3 values from the first, second, third and fourth rows each.

This is what I tried:

```
from itertools import product
uniques = [df[i].unique().tolist() for i in df.columns ]
pd.DataFrame(product(*uniques), columns = df.columns)
```

But this generates all combinations with all 6 columns like this:

```
 0           1             2            3             4              5              6
Table       Black         Brown       Red           Blue          Green           Aqua
Table       Black         Brown       Red           Blue          Green          Violet
```

Here, all values of Row 1 remain the same except for the last value, and all combinations are generated like this.

But what I need is this:

```
 0       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
Table   Black    Red     Blue    Magenta   White   Orange   Yellow    Peach     Aqua
```

Here, the first three values are from Row 1, the second 3 values are from Row 2, and the last 3 values are from Row 3.
Similarly, I want to display all such sets, and store them in a new dataframe.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The column 0 is included?

Comment: Why you use "unique". Do the rows have repeated values inside each row, or also between rows?

Comment: @Colim it is possible that multiple rows have the same value. What I am looking to avoid is having repeated values within each set of combinations generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
df
###
        0        1          2         3       4       5      6
0   Table    Black      Brown       Red    Blue   Green  Amber
1   Chair  Magenta  Turquoise     White  Orange  Violet   Pink
2  Window   Indigo     Yellow  Cerulean    Grey   Peach   Aqua
```

```
from itertools import product
import random
uniques = [df[i].unique().tolist() for i in df.columns]
rl = list(product(*uniques))
pd.DataFrame(random.choices(rl))
```

`product()` generates all the combinations from sets, but you want a random result from the combinations list.

```
       0      1      2      3       4      5     6
0  Table  Black  Brown  White  Orange  Peach  Aqua
```

---

#### Supplement

Combination
with 3 sets.
[image]

Select one element from each set, how many combinations would be?
2 * 2 * 3 = 12

Let's check whether the total number of all combinations is 12 or not.

```
list_of_lists = [['Yellow','Blue'],['Cat','Dog'],['Swim','Run','Sleep']]

combination = product(*list_of_lists)
combination_list = list(combination)

pd.DataFrame(combination_list)
###
         0    1      2
0   Yellow  Cat   Swim
1   Yellow  Cat    Run
2   Yellow  Cat  Sleep
3   Yellow  Dog   Swim
4   Yellow  Dog    Run
5   Yellow  Dog  Sleep
6     Blue  Cat   Swim
7     Blue  Cat    Run
8     Blue  Cat  Sleep
9     Blue  Dog   Swim
10    Blue  Dog    Run
11    Blue  Dog  Sleep
```

And choose one row from above randomly, would be the solution to generate a set from combinations.

Comment: What I am looking to get is all possible sets, with an equal number of values taken from each row. For example, all sets containing 9 columns each (excluding column 0), containing 3 values from each row.

Comment: `rl` is all combination of sets(Solution sets, Range), that's why your `head(2)` only contains one difference in the last column, it's like combinations from set(a,b) with set(c, d), the first combination would be `ac`, and `ad`, `bc` and `bd`.